# Webcam effects for Windows 7

Tags: windows, skype, webcam, google-talk

I need a software that can creates effects in webcam for video chat in Google and Skype. I can do effects with HP touchsmart softwares. but not able to do the same for Google talk or Skype.

EDIT: Effects like big eyes, big nose, bulging head, overlaying hats, hair etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're very non-specific about what sort of "effects" you want, but I suspect [ManyCam](http://manycam.com/) might fit the bill here.

Comment: Effects like big eyes, big nose, bulging head, overlaying hats, hair etc.

Comment: many cam doesn't do those effects

Comment: It does in fact do some of those, but not all. Thank you for actually clarifying - a lot of folks will never bother even when asked!  I'll leave the answer here in case it's ever useful to anyone else, though.

Answer (score 0):

if you have HP touchsmart ... go to your skype/gtalk configuration menu: tools/options/video and select the "HP webcam filter or HP webcam splitter"

, then the messaging application will use your HP webcam and you will be able to use all the effects during your video call.

Hope it helps

Willy